# How can I forward the user to other page/path in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am implementing a simple login page, and I want to forward the user to another page/path after selecting an identity.

```
import {useState} from "react";
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Select from 'react-select';
import './Login.css';

export default function Login(){
    const [technician,setTechnician]=useState();
    let options=[
        {label:"Jack", value:"2432244cvdsffsd2342434"}
    ];

    let doLogin=()=>{
        if (technician){
            sessionStorage.setItem("technican",JSON.stringify(technician));
            return <Navigate to='/request'/>
        }else {
            alert("Please select your name to login.");
        }
    }
    let handleChange=(value)=>{
        setTechnician(value);
    }
    return (
        <Container>
            Login:
            <Select
                isClearable
                onChange={handleChange}
                options={options} 
                placeholder="Please select your name to login"/>
            <button onClick={doLogin}>Login</button>    
        </Container>
    )
}
```

I am using react-router v6.

`"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2"`

**Expected Result:**

1. user selects identity from the drop-down.
2. Click on the "login" button. It should forward the user to the "/request" path

**Actual Result:**

The page does not forward users to the "/request" path.

Would you tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by `useNavigate` hook in react-router-dom v6, like this:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...
export default function Login(){
   const navigate = useNavigate();
   ...
    let doLogin=()=>{
      if (technician){
        sessionStorage.setItem("technican",JSON.stringify(technician));
        navigate('/request');
      }else {
        alert("Please select your name to login.");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be `react-router-dom`

Comment: Right, I edited my answer, thank you so much.

Comment: I will give a tick to your answer as soon as the system allow me to do so.

Comment: @TheKNVB for version <6^, earlier `useHistory` hook was used but now it got changed

Answer (score 1):

- For the version of `react router dom` less than `6.^`

You can use `useHistory()` hook like this.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
...
export default function Login(){
   let history = useHistory();
   ...
    let doLogin=()=>{
      if (technician){
        ...
        history.push('/request');
      }
      else {
        ...     }
   }
}
```

- For the latest version of `react router dom` greater than `6.^`

You can use `useNavigate()` hook like this.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...
export default function Login(){
   let navigate = useNavigate();
   ...
    let doLogin=()=>{
      if (technician){
        ...
        navigate('/request');
      }
      else {
        ...     }
   }
}
```